# Service Stack - Custom authentication on one route

Tags: authentication, servicestack, jwt

In my current application, I am using Service Stack with JWT's for security.  Security has been implemented and works perfectly.  Trouble is,  I would like to secure one route differently from the others.  There is a document the logged in user retrieves, I want to make sure the document they are retrieving is theirs and not someone else's.  It is very sensitive data.  I would like to secure it differently because something like PostMan could be used with a valid token to retrieve any document, I want to prevent this.  The users id is in the token, I would like to match it against the document that is being retrieved if possible.  The current security is implemented like so:

```
public class AppHost: AppHostBase
{

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
           new IAuthProvider[] {
            new JsonWebTokenAuthProvider("myKey", "myAudience"),
        }));
    }
}
```

`JsonWebTokenAuthProvider` is a custom class where security was implemented, this all works perfectly.  Here is the code:

```
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        // first validate the token, then get roles from session
        string header = request.oauth_token;

        // if no auth header, 401
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        {
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized(MissingAuthHeader);
        }

        string[] headerData = header.Split(' ');

        // if header is missing bearer portion, 401
        if (!string.Equals(headerData[0], "BEARER", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized(InvalidAuthHeader);
        }

        // swap - and _ with their Base64 string equivalents
        string secret = SymmetricKey.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        string token = headerData[1].Replace("\"", "");
        // set current principal to the validated token principal

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = JsonWebToken.ValidateToken(token, secret, Audience, true, Issuer);
        string lanId = GetLanID(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        string proxyAsLanId = request.Meta.ContainsKey(META_PROXYID) ? request.Meta[META_PROXYID] : null;

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            // set the current request's user the the decoded principal
            HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        }

        // set the session's username to the logged in user
        session.UserName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
        session.Roles = GetApplicableRoles(lanId, proxyAsLanId);

        authService.Request.SetItem("lanID", lanId);
        authService.Request.SetItem("proxyAsLanId", proxyAsLanId);

        return OnAuthenticated(authService, session, null, null);
    }
```

I looked up `RequestFilterAttribute` found [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes), but I do not think that is what I want.  Ideally, if the check fails I would like to return a 401 (unauthorized) if possible.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to handle one route differently than you can just add the validation in your single Service, e.g:

```
public object Any(MyRequest dto)
{
    var lanId = base.Request.GetItem("lanId");
    if (!MyIsValid(lanId))
        throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Custom Auth Validation failed");   
}
```

You could do the same in a RequestFilter, e.g:

```
public class CustomAuthValidationAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object responseDto)
    {
        var lanId = req.GetItem("lanId");
        if (!MyIsValid(lanId))
        {
            res.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            res.StatusDescription = "Custom Auth Validation failed";
            res.EndRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

And apply it to a single Service:

```
[CustomAuthValidation]
public object Any(MyRequest dto)
{
    //...
}
```

Or a collection of Services, e.g:

```
[CustomAuthValidation]
public class MyAuthServices : Service
{
    public object Any(MyRequest1 dto)
    {
        //...
    }
    public object Any(MyRequest2 dto)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you :D